# Is it possible to get the contents of an external css file using javascript to add to an svg file?

Tags: javascript, css, svg

I need to get the contents of an external css file in order to add it to an svg.

What I'm looking for is in effect a toString method for the css. Is this possible? I haven't been able to find a solution yet.

Here is the solution xml I'm looking for for the svg :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
    <!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" 
      "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1"
         width="10cm" height="5cm" viewBox="0 0 1000 500">
      <defs>
        <style type="text/css"><![CDATA[
          rect {
            fill: red;
            stroke: blue;
            stroke-width: 3
          }
        ]]></style>
      </defs>
      <rect x="200" y="100" width="600" height="300"/>
    </svg>
```

I tried using an external link to it but it didn't render the styles :

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="mystyle.css" type="text/css"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" 
  "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1"
     width="10cm" height="5cm" viewBox="0 0 1000 500">
  <rect x="200" y="100" width="600" height="300"/>
</svg>
```

**Edit : I should have added this origionally**
I have the svg rendering fine within the browser as it has access to the svg.

What I need to do is send the svg to a server for further processing (convert format, save to database..). The problem is that the style is lost as the css is not included in the svg xml. I need to add the css to the svg itself like the first block of code above so I can keep the stylings.

Comment: use ajax and then get the style?

Comment: The external link should work provided you serve it with the correct mime type.

Comment: Are you already able to retrive the content of the css file and you _only_ don't know how to extract the specific part? is the external css of the same domain?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are able to use JavaScript you can get the contents of your stylesheet as follows:

```
[].slice.call(document.styleSheets[1].cssRules).forEach(function(rule){
  console.log('rule:', rule.cssText)
})
```

Where `document.styleSheets[1]` is your stylesheet.

Comment: Thank you.this does the job. However specifying an array index doesn't seem like the best option. Is there a way to retrieve the file based on its name?

Comment: Maybe you could try adding a class name on the link tag, then iterating over all stylesheets to look for a match. Something like `if (document.styleSheets[i].ownerNode.className == 'yourclass') { //...get rules... }`